# How to reload the page right on the first second of next day ? at midnight?

Tags: javascript

I have a dashboard page that users left open on the TV overnight.

I noticed there was a bug last night, it needs to `reload` as soon as it detects a new day.
Let's say today is `4/29`. So, right at the first second of `4/30`, I need to **reload** the page.
I use moment.js in my application. I'm not sure if I should load the page at midnight `12:00 PM` or at `12:01 AM`. I'm afraid that when I do it at 12:00 PM, it still considering the day as `4/29` making the reloading never happen and the bug   still being there.

```
if(moment("24:00:00", "hh:mm:ss").diff(moment(), 'seconds') == 0){
    location.reload();
}
```

or should I do this?

```
if(moment().format("h") == 12){
    location.reload();
}
```

How do I make sure that? How to verify that ?

---

## Edit

I have this code

```
    //====================================
    //              RUN every 1 mn = 60 s
    //====================================
    window.setInterval(function () {

        getNextFeed('{{ $baby->id }}');

        if(moment("24:00:00", "hh:mm:ss").diff(moment(), 'seconds') == -1){
            location.reload();
        }

    }, 60000);
```

I  just added it there.

Comment: Oh boy, just set it to min from NOW and see if it will reload. And just switch to 24 hour like the rest of the world, and set it to reload at 00:00:01, if time is 00:00:01 // reload... Keep i mind you will have to run this function every second if you need to target seconds.

Comment: I would suggest fixing the bug, instead of implementing a workaround like this.

Comment: @ikiK running it every second? having the if-check is not enough?

Comment: @cyb3rZ No you need to update current time every second to compare it,

Comment: @trincot I would rather do that too, it's not a straightforward one. The application don't have/need page-refresh during the day as soon as the date value updated, it messed up.

Comment: @ikiK `if(moment("24:00:00", "hh:mm:ss").diff(moment(), 'seconds') == -1){ ... }`

Comment: @ikiK `moment()` will give current time.

Comment: I never used it but console log(moment()) and see if time is moving forward. If you see it static, you need to update it yourself.

Comment: @ikiK I updated my post, see Edit. I think it might works, you think so too ?

Comment: since I need to make a call to get the nextFeed data every mn anyway, mine as well check if the midnight or not at that moment too ...

Comment: Yes that should work. Console log it inside interval and see whats happening. You should be good. And you need to do it insde interval cose if only runs once on load, you need to repeat condition.

Comment: Can you add an answer for  `inside interval cose if only runs once on load, you need to repeat condition` ?

Comment: All good, and there is anwser now, seems ok.

Comment: @ikiK I felt like now my code will load every mn after midnight, how do to make it load only one time per day.

Answer (score 3):

No need for moment at all, here is vanilla solution that will reload page if time is 23:59, and will check if that is true every second.

You can lift an interval to few more seconds or every half minute, it will make no change and set your desired time inside   `if (nowHour == 23 && nowMinuts == 59)`

If you need to target seconds also, then include that in `if` and leave interval at every second.
But if you include second cheeking then do : `if (nowHour == 23 && nowMinuts == 59 && nowSecunds >= 55)`
with `>=`  to make sure it will fire with 5 second window just in case.

But i believe you are perfectly fine with just minutes.

```js
setInterval(function() {
  let nowHour = new Date().getHours()
  let nowMinuts = new Date().getMinutes()
  let nowSecunds = new Date().getSeconds()

  console.log("Hour " + nowHour + " Minutes " + nowMinuts + " Secunds " + nowSecunds)

  if (nowHour == 23 && nowMinuts == 59) {
    location.reload();
  }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this reload the page every second for a minute at 23:59?

Comment: @GRX actually you are right... Some local storage checks can to be added, so it stores the value on reload... good point... OR just put seconds cheek also, and fire it in 5 sec window, it should run only once, or twice...

Answer (score 2):

You may store the current date when page loaded, and if the date changed, it means "next day" started.

```js
const getDate = () => moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')

const pageLoadDate = getDate() // store current date, e.g. 2021-04-29
setInterval(() => {
    if (pageLoadDate !== getDate()) {
        location.reload()
    }
}, 60000)
```

Comment: I have `window.setInterval(function () {` is it same as your `setInterval()`

Comment: While code only anwser may solve the issue they are not welcomed on SO, please explain the code, as you see now in comments OP needs help understanding what needs to be done. So he can learn for next time.

Comment: @cyb3rZ  `window.setInterval === setInterval` === `true`   `window` acts like a global in Javascript. eg.. `globalThis` also equals `window`